# Tictactoe score check through a hash

Tags: ruby, data-structures, hashmap

I've been working on a command-line Tictactoe game written in Ruby. (For the ones who don't remember the rules, please [see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tic-tac-toe))

Almost all of the example implementations that I've seen uses a multi-dimensional array to represent `Board` structure. It's like `[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]`. ([Here is an example](https://codequizzes.wordpress.com/2013/10/25/creating-a-tic-tac-toe-game-with-ruby/))

However, before seeing any other solutions I started with a hash implementation. I represent columns with letters (A,B,C) and rows with numbers (1,2,3) and I set "X" or "O" as the value. Example implementation during a game:

```
{:a1=>"X", :b2=>"X", :c3=>"X", :b1=>"O", :c1=>"X", :c2=>"O", :b3=>"X", :a2=>"O", :a3=>"X"}
```

(At every move, I add the new position to this hash. It's kind of a cell grid. Easy to visualize inside an ASCII table.)

Everything felt great until I started to look for a way to determine the winning positions. But now I'm stucked at finding a good way to use my hash to determine if it's a winner position.

Could you please show me how to solve the problem using hashes? And/or can you please explain why it's a bad idea to use a hash instead of a multi-dimensional array in this particular scenario?

Here is a bad looking way of checking if it's a winner position or not (For a single scenario..):

```
  def check_status
    if(@@cells[:a1] == "X" && @@cells[:a2] == "X" && @@cells[:a3] == "X")
      false # game will end
    else
      true # game will continue
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given this hash:

```
board = {
  :a1=>"X", :a2=>"O", :a3=>"X",
  :b1=>"O", :b2=>"X", :b3=>"X",
  :c1=>"X", :c2=>"O", :c3=>"X"
}
```

You could define the keys to be checked: (the possible winning positions)

```
KEYS = [
  [:a1, :a2, :a3], [:b1, :b2, :b3], [:c1, :c2, :c3], # rows
  [:a1, :b1, :c1], [:a2, :b2, :c2], [:a3, :b3, :c3], # columns
  [:a1, :b2, :c3], [:c1, :b2, :a3]                   # diagonals
]
```

Now you can fetch the values for each of these keys via [`values_at`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Hash.html#method-i-values_at) and check if they are either `"X", "X", "X"` or `"O", "O", "O"`:

```
wins = {}

KEYS.each do |k|
  case board.values_at(*k)
  when %w[X X X] then wins[k] = 'X'
  when %w[O O O] then wins[k] = 'O'
  end
end

wins #=> {[:a3, :b3, :c3]=>"X", [:a1, :b2, :c3]=>"X", [:c1, :b2, :a3]=>"X"}
```